# Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i get this error when trying to connect to a db setup on mongolab

```
Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]
```

however, my connection URI is:

```
'user' :  'mongodb://dbuserNameString:dbPasswordString@ds027789.mongolab.com:27789/db1'
```

so where does undefined come from?

Comment: Is your uri inside of a json document? How did you assign the uri to 'user'. Also, can you include the line of code where you use that connection string?

Comment: no its not json. the code is from a tutorial @ http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: Well, you should really post your own code, but here goes... Your `config/database.js` is exporting `user`, but the tutorial calls out `url`. If you are following the tutorial to a 't', that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [the tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local#database-config-config/database.js) you mentioned, you have to use the `url` instead of `user`, the change should be:

```
'url' :  'mongodb://dbuserNameString:dbPasswordString@ds027789.mongolab.com:27789/db1'
```